# How to read ABAP code using a java client

Tags: abap

I have a requirement were I need to read ABAP code written by SAP developers. I want to write my own client using Java/Python which can integrate with SAP system and get me the ABAP code.

What I understand that ABAP code is stored in SAP database like HANA, mysql etc. So is there a way which SAP provides where we can read the code like we can do in Git/SVN etc.

Comment: Some ideas: ABAP source code is stored in database table `REPOSRC`, but compressed using an internal SAP algorithm. To extract it, you must create an ABAP program with the statement `READ REPORT` and make the program callable externally (SAP protocol RFC, or any classic way like HTTP). You may also push the source code outside via the ABAP tool [abapGit](https://github.com/larshp/abapGit), to a HTTP Git repository. Eventually you may create an ABAP program that you call, which executes abapGit. The advantage of using abapGit is that it outputs other SAP code objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can access tables with below techniques:

- Using [SAP Connectors](https://support.sap.com/en/product/connectors.html) via RFC (RFC_READ_TABLE)
- Using SOAP Web Service with same function (RFC_READ_TABLE)
- Using custom web services with existing functions which are reading report, functions, etc.

You can use both Java or Pyhton for RFC, there is already exits github repo for [python](https://github.com/SAP/PyRFC).

If you will select reading directly in db table, you need to know structure of saved data. It has own mechanism for OOP objects. Daniel Berlin try to implement binary parser in C++ in [sap-reposrc-decompressor](https://gitlab.com/daberlin/sap-reposrc-decompressor) project. Never forget this source depended with SAP version.

I think using ADT (ABAP Development Tools) plugin is good for updated systems. There is already Eclipse plugin exists for ADT. ADT not exists in old systems.

If you are planning to use your solution in old system (after 7.01), you can build your own solution with [abapGit](https://github.com/larshp/abapGit) and custom web services.

**NOTE**: Keep in mind, report and data elements (variables, tables, types) saved in separate tables. Dynpro objects (screens etc), reports (Smartforms) hard things to decompile.

Answer (score 1):

I've used RFC calls `RPY_FUNCTIONMODULE_READ` and `RPY_FUNCTIONMODULE_READ_NEW` through the perl NWRFC wrapper/library to retreive ABAP code.

Answer (score 1):

Before you re-invent a wheel, Take a look at:

- ABAPgit.    https://docs.abapgit.org/
- or the old  SAPLink   https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/SAPlink.

If you want JUST the source code, You could expose a very simple rest service/ Endpoint  in SAP.
This service would just read the raw code and return it as plain text.
Every abaper could create this for you.
BUT is the raw source only. There is much more to a complete development
and why tools like ABAPGIT exist.

In SICF, create a new endpoint / service.
EG ZCODE_MONKEY with the class below as an example.

[image: SICF entry]

Now activate the service.

Call the endpoint
http://server:PORT/zcode_monkey?name=ZCODE_MONKEY

**Sample implementation**

```
CLASS zcode_monkey DEFINITION
  PUBLIC
  CREATE PUBLIC .
  PUBLIC SECTION.
  INTERFACES: if_http_extension.
ENDCLASS.
CLASS zcode_monkey IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD if_http_extension~handle_request.
      DATA: lo_src type ref to CL_OO_SOURCE,
            l_name TYPE string,
            l_repname type c length 30,
            l_clskey type seoclskey ,
            l_source type rswsourcet,
            resultcode TYPE string.
      FIELD-SYMBOLS: <line> TYPE LINE OF rswsourcet.

    l_name =    server->request->get_form_field(  name    = 'NAME' ).

    l_clskey = l_name.
    l_repname = l_name.

    create OBJECT lo_src
      EXPORTING
        clskey             = l_clskey
      EXCEPTIONS
        class_not_existing = 1
        others             = 2      .

    IF sy-subrc <> 0.
       read REPORT l_repname into l_source.
    else.
      lo_src->read( ).
      lo_src->if_oo_clif_source~get_source(  IMPORTING source = l_source   ).
    ENDIF.


    LOOP AT l_source ASSIGNING <line>.

      CONCATENATE  resultCode
                   cl_abap_char_utilities=>cr_lf
                   <line>
            INTO   resultCode   RESPECTING BLANKS. " always show respect ;)


    ENDLOOP.

    SErver->response->set_content_type( content_type = 'text/plain' ).
    server->response->set_cdata( EXPORTING  data   = resultcode ).
    server->response->set_status(
      EXPORTING
        code   = 200
        reason = 'this is a 3.50 piece of code. Dont ask...its a demo ' ).
  ENDMETHOD.

ENDCLASS.
```